# Problem with camera concerning file names und photos app

Tags: camera, storage, photos, files

### **Short version:**

How can the camera app be brought to save pictures again with the regular format "IMG_2021....jpg"? On my Nokia 7.2 this is not the case anymore (see picture).

[image: Screenshot of Windows file explorer]

### **Long version / additional explanations:**

Before I bought my Nokia 7.2, I used the SD card already in a Samsung Galaxy Note und hatte and had stored on it (among other) several pictures. For the new pictures, a new folder was automatically created and the old pictures remained saved.

Sometime, an additional folder was automatically created without that I had anything to do with it, maybe due to an update. After that there were three subfolders in DCIM, both on the device and on the SD card:

- 100ANDRO (probably from Galaxy Note, but I'm not sure anymore)
- Kamera
- Camera
  From then on, the pictures got stored in the folder "Camera". Until that point, everything was allright.

At the end of last year I noticed that new pictures don't get stored anymore with the regular format "IMG_2020....jpg" but instead with an unlogical file name, see screenshot of Windows file explorer. Only newly created videos still get stored with with the regular format.

A few days ahaid of that, the following had happend:
The "Fotos" app from Google suddenly claimed that there was no access to delete pictures (which had always worked before) and that I should use the gallery app for that. Therefore I installed Google Gallery and for comparison one or two additional gallery apps. I then could delete pictures directly again and didn't have to switch to the "Files" app or another one.

When I realised the new file naming of the pictures I first thought, it might have something to do with the installation of the gallery apps and I removed them again. However, that had no effect.

My next attempt has probably caused a subsequent problem, but didn't solve the original issue: In the system settings I deleted the cache and data of the apps "Kamera" (Google Camera) and "Fotos" (Google Photos). Since then, new pictures are still stored with the 'wrong' file name.
On the other hand, I noticed - just a few days later - that many old pictures are missing. The folders "100ANDRO" are both empty, both on the device and the SD card. At least the folder on the SD card had contained several pictures before. The two "Kamera" folders have vanished with the containing pictures. From all the created pictures I don't have anymore those from about 1 1/2 years.

I find it disturbing that pictures made with the camera are removed when deleting the data of any app. From my point of view, the folder DCIM does not belong to any app at all, as opposed to f. ex. the folder WhatsAppImages in WhatsApp > Media. Anyhow, I probably have to live with that; a restore of the deleted pictures is rather time consuming and/or expensive.

But how can the Google Camera app be brought to store the pictures again with the regular format "IMG_2021....jpg"?

Thanks for your help or any tipps.

By the way, why does the Camera app frequently change the storage folder from sd card to device? (If I'm not mistaken, this didn't only happen after installing updates.)